# polymer 1.0 how to central justify the paper-card heading?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying this to central justify the paper card heading:

```html
paper-card [heading]{
      @apply(--center-justified);
    }
```

but it does not seem to help. kindly suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heading` is not an `attribute` so you cannot write like that.

You basically need to style the `.title-text` element inside the shadow dom, so use this instead -

```
paper-card::shadow #shadow .header .title-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Or use the *polymer* `iron-flex-layout` -

```
paper-card::shadow #shadow .header .title-text {
    @apply(--layout-vertical);
    @apply(--layout-center);
}
```

---

### Update

Thanks to @sfeast for pointing it out. Since `shadow` selectors will be deprecated, the above styles need to be applied to the *mixins* like this -

```
paper-card {
    --paper-card-header: {
        @apply(--layout-vertical);
        @apply(--layout-center);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is going to break since the shadow selector is/has been already I believe, deprecated.

The `--paper-card-header` mixin is available for what you would like to do. See the example for using mixins here - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins

Comment: Hey thanks! I wasn't aware of this. I've updated my answer and it looks better now. :)