# Polymer-project: paper-card image style under #shadow-root is not working

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have working on Polymer 2.0, and used polymer `paper-card` to display some text and an image. I need to apply style to the image that is under `<iron-image>#shadow-root`

Code below:

```
<paper-card elevation="1" aria-label="">

<iron-image>
#shadow-root
<img id="img" hidden="" src="/images/image.jpg">
</iron-image>

<div class="card-content">
<h2>Title</h2>
Some text here..
</div>
</paper-card>
```

Tried css rule from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025876/6191987

```
paper-card iron-image::shadow #shadow img {
   display: block;      
}
```

but it is not working for me. Have this contain anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `paper-card ::slotted(iron-image)`.  Check out the link [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-slotted-content-distributed-children) on styling distributed children.

You could also try `--paper-card-header-image` in css, like:

```
paper-card {
    --paper-card-header-image: {
        display: block;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.. but it is not workig for me